# Kubernetes Dashboards are unauthorised. how to configure

Tags: kubernetes, coreos

I am following the tutorial from [Kubernetes on AWS](https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/kubernetes-on-aws.html) by Coreos (I need a Cloudformation template) to create a Kubernetes inside my already existing VPC.

Everything is configured properly and the cluster was successfully setup, but i am experiencing difficulties with Heapster/KubeDNS

My cluster info and config view look like this:

> ```
> kubectl --kubeconfig=kubeconfig cluster-info
> Kubernetes master is running at https://my-cluster-endpoint.company.com.
> Heapster is running at https://my-cluster-endpoint.company.com./api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/heapster
> KubeDNS is running at https://my-cluster-endpoint.company.com./api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns
>
> kubectl --kubeconfig=kubeconfig config view
> apiVersion: v1
> clusters:
> - cluster:
>     certificate-authority: credentials/ca.pem
>     server: https://my-cluster-endpoint.company.com.
>   name: kube-aws-my-cluster-name-cluster
> contexts:
> - context:
>     cluster: kube-aws-my-cluster-name-cluster
>     namespace: default
>     user: kube-aws-my-cluster-name-admin
>   name: kube-aws-my-cluster-name-context
> current-context: kube-aws-my-cluster-name-context
> kind: Config
> preferences: {}
> users:
> - name: kube-aws-my-cluster-name-admin
>   user:
>     client-certificate: credentials/admin.pem
>     client-key: credentials/admin-key.pem
> ```

So a few problems that I notice compared to the [getting started guides from kubernetes.io](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/aws/):

1. All the "out of the box" services like Kibana/Grafana are missing (but these you can probably install yourself)
2. There is no "user" section with username and password to enter the dashboards only one with certificate

As well when I try to reach these endpoints I immediately get "unauthorised" and the api does not even challenge me for username password

So how do I set basic authentication for my newly created cluster OR is there a way to login with the .pem certificate?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CoreOS-kubernetes tooling is meant to deploy a fully functioning Kubernetes cluster, but leave optional/ addon applications as a decision for the cluster admin. In this case kibana & grafana are not strictly required for a fully functioning cluster -- so they are not deployed by default.

Similarly with authentication, basic-auth is not enabled by default (cert based auth and Bearer tokens are). However, you should be able to add basic auth by creating a file and a adding a flag to the api-server manifest:

- Create a basic auth file following the format described here: http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authentication
- In `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml`, add a flag pointing to the file you created above `--basic-auth-file=SOMEFILE`

When you make the change to the `kube-apiserver.yaml` manifest, the kubelet will see the change an automatically restart the pod. If you're running apiservers on multiple hosts, be sure to make the above changes to each.

Another option is to use the `kubectl proxy` command to first authenticate against your api-server. See: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/connecting-to-applications-proxy - essentially the kubectl proxy will authenticate then allow you to access the endpoint locally on your machine.

Comment: With `kubectl proxy --port=9999`, Chrome tells me "This site can’t provide a secure connection" when I try to connect to 127.0.0.1:9999. curl says:

`$ curl -v https://127.0.0.1:9999/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to 127.0.0.1:-9847`

Any ideas why?